# internal links not working on multipage document

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I have a multi page document and the home page links to other pages without a hitch however if I try to link to another page from the content of a page it does nothing, the link is just dead. same on mobile and desktop. Here is the code for the whole of page 4 (the page where I am trying to insert these links) My document has 7 pages in total. The first issue is on line 16, my link is:

```
<a href="#webdesign">
```

however this does nothing even though I have a page called 'webdesign'

```
<!-- Start of fourth page -->
<script>
$(document).on('click', 'a.webdesign', function () { $.mobile.changePage('#webdesign'); });
</script>    

<div data-role="page" id="services">

<div data-role="header1">
<div align="center"><img src="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/images/magnetikmedia_header.png" width="90%"></div>
</div>
<div>
<div align="center"><img src="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/images/services_banner.png" width="100%"></div>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
<div data-role="collapsible-set">

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>Website Design</h3>
<p>We offer a full website design service whether you are looking for a basic, low maintenance site to create your online presence, a responsive site to attract more mobile browsers or an advanced, dynamic e-commerce site to power your business to the next level. We also offer a website content management service so whether you need any information editing or amending your current site or would like a page or two adding then we can do this for you. <a href="#" class="webdesign">Read more about our website design services</a></p>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>facebook Development</h3>
<p>The most striking part of any facebook business page is the cover image. This, along with your profile, can make or break a facebook page. We design custom cover images perfectly suited to your industry and business to really enable you to stand out and make visitors want to 'like' you! <a href="#facebookdesign">Read more about facebook timeline design</a></p>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>twitter Design</h3>
<p>We can create custom backgrounds for your Twitter pages that can incorporate your logo, contact details or, in fact, anything you like. This helps you move one step closer to catching the eye of potential customers who will be passing by (and there will be a lot based on the fact there are over 140 million active users!) <a href="#twitterdesign">Read more about twitter design</a></p>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>Email Marketing</h3>
<p>Our dynamic e-mail campaign service means we can create a custom newsletter, an advert for a special offer or just a courtesy message to your customer base that is professionally designed and can be mailed out to as many customers as you wish. Not only that but it will be fully trackable so you can keep tabs on who has read the email or who has yet to open it. We can even add a secure, online subscription form to your website or facebook page where potential new customers can sign up to your mailing campaigns which are then integrated automatically so they are ready to be included in your next mailout.  <a href="#emailmarketing">Read more about email marketing</a></p>
</div>

<div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="true">
<h3>Animation</h3>
<p>From animated email footers to full promotional videos, flash animation can be a useful tool to showcase your product or services to the world in an attractive and fun way. <a href="#animation">Read more about our animation services</a></p>
</div>

</div>
<div align="center"><!-- /content -->


<div id="footer1">
<div id="footer_left">
<div align="center"><a href="http://www.facebook.com/magnetikmedia"><img src="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/images/fbook_foot.png" width="30" height="30" style="margin-right:10px;" ></a><a href="http://www.twitter.com/magnetikmedia"><img src="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/images/twitter_foot.png" width="30" height="30" style="margin-right:10px;" ></a><a href="http://magnetikmedia.blogspot.co.uk"><img src="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/images/blogger_foot.png" width="30" height: "30" style="margin-right:10px;" ></a><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/in/magnetikmedia"><img src="http://www.magnetikmedia.co.uk/m/images/linkedin_foot.png" width="113" height="30" style="margin-right:10px;" ></a></div>
</div>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
</div>
  <div align="center"><!-- /footer -->
```

Comment: Try `<a href="#" class='webdesign'>` and once clicked `$(document).on('click', 'a.webdesign', function () { $.mobile.changePage('#webdesign'); });`.

Comment: Thanks. Being a newbie to jquerymobile, can you tell me where the '$(document).on('click'' code goes? In the head section?

Comment: Anywhere, but make sure you give the page an id webdesign.

Comment: Done that but not working. Just trying to work out how to post my code in this reply! Can't see a code option

Comment: Wrap ur code with `` or just update ur question.

Comment: Cant work out how to post code in a reply so added the .on('click'' code into the head section in <script> tags and changed <a href="#facebookdesign"> to <a href="#" class='webdesign'> but still a dead link

Comment: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Palestinian/7fmqh/ check this.

Comment: Put the code ive given you in the body

Comment: I put the 'on click' code in the body section and changed the link back to <a href="#webdesign"> as per your jsfiddle but still no luck. I can't post the code, putting it in " doesn't do anything. Sorry for sounding like an idiot, I'm fairly new to query and new to stackoverflow

Comment: Link should look this way `<a href="#" class="webdesign">any text </a>`

Comment: Yeah thats how it is, the code is updated in the question now. To keep things tidy, I put the on click code right at the top of the relevant page in question, I think the issue is where I am puttting this code is it?

Comment: Do you have a page with ID webdesign? `<div data-role="page" id=webdesign>`

Comment: Yep, page 5 <!-- Start of fifth page -->
<div data-role="page" id="webdesign">

Comment: Sorry `<!-- Start of fifth page --> <div data-role="page" id="webdesign">`

Comment: If other links/pages work, then there must be something missing in that page. Make sure you don't have a missing tag or close page div. or some elements have id webdesign.

Comment: Yeah, I think that too maybe. Each section of the 'services' page has links to other pages and none of them work either. The only ones that do are on the homepage in the main list where `<a href="#about">` `<a href="#getsocial">` etc. work fine. I'll scan through the code and update you.

Comment: I was missing a closing div on the page! Thanks for your help. I do have one more issue so will make a new post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was one closing div missing, added that and all fixed.